# Flutter Firestore Database with StreamBuilder: Get access to documents subcollection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore Database with a collection 'multiChannels'. This collection has a Document that has some fields AND a subcollection. Can I get access to the subcollection in the StreamBuilder?

```
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('multiChannels').snapshots(), 
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              print('in ListView.builder');
              Map data = snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();
              print('data: $data'); // fine
              // The following doesn't work
              var collection = snapshot.data!.docs[index].collection();
              return const SizedBox();
            },
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Error');
        } else {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      },
    );
```

Comment: Firebase queries are shallow, the stream will fetch one document, and you need another query to get the documents in the sub collection. You can access it with `...collection('<collection name>')` but it will not contain the documents in the sub collection.

Comment: You can have for example a `FutureBuilder` inside the `StreamBuilder` to get the documents in the sub collection.

Comment: My workaround was to store the subcollection-data as a map in the document.

Comment: Tanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

> Can I get access to the sub-collection in the StreamBuilder?

No. If you read a document, it doesn't mean that you have access to the sub-collections that exist under the document. As @PeterKoltai mentioned in his comment, Firestore queries are shallow. This means that it can only return documents from the collection that the query is run against. There is no way you can get documents from a top-level collection and a sub-collection in a single query. If you need documents that exist in sub-collection, then you have to perform a separate query.

> My workaround was to store the subcollection data as a map in the document.

Yes, that's a really good approach, but please note that, when it comes to storing data in a document, there are some limitations. You can store only up to [1 MiB](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits). So if you store large objects inside a single document, you should take care of the limitation. Otherwise, store the data as documents inside a sub-collection where there is no limitation on how many documents you can add.

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the answer! Perhaps you have an idea about this problem too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76175711/flutter-how-to-show-overlay-correctly-when-hovering-listtile 
I have a working solution with 3 timers, but perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: Before seeing the new question, did this answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Your answer helped me, thanks! At the moment, I don't need further information about this topic.